# Drag And Drop a panels in WebPage using jquery ,css, html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to Jquery, I am trying to:

1. create 2 panels side by side and able to drag and drop each other by holding on header part of panel
2. I need to show placeholder at back

I have created 2 panels, but I am unable to drag them, I dont know where I went wrong can anyone offer some advice?

http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/AJ2XT/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the JQuery UI's draggable.
Just google JQuery draggable for plenty of good examples

Comment: I checked out And posted hear, i am searching for this drag and drop for days